# Not focused inputs after click submit button in jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form(which submit by ajax)

```
<form action="/Home/Contact" method="POST" id="form0" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="FullName">name</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20px">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="please enter name" id="FullName" name="FullName" placeholder="name" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="From">email</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20px">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="please enter valid email" data-val-required="please enter email" id="From" name="From" placeholder="email" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Message">message</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20px">
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-0">
                            <textarea class="form-control resize-vertical" cols="4" data-val="true" data-val-required="please enter message" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="message" rows="4"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" data-rel="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="loading..." data-ajax-submit="">send</button>

                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">reset</button>
                </p>
</form>
```

and javascript code is:

```
    $("[data-ajax-submit]").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $button = $(this);
        var $form = $button.closest('form');

        var val = $form.validate();
        val.form();
        val.valid();
    });
```

after submit form, inputs highlighted by jquery validation BUT inputs `not focused`, why?

a note:

when i remove `event.preventDefault()` works BUT send form send in normal postback and not in ajax post.

Answer (score 1):

That is, you prevented default behavior and hence onfocus event is not bubbled to textbox. What you can do is remove preventDefault() call and at the end of your click handler either set the focus manually by calling `focus()` or `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `invalidHandler` inside `validate` method:

```
$form.validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {                    
            validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
        }
    } 
});
```